# Appending multiple FeatureClasses to one another gives ERROR 000735?

Tags: arcpy, merge, feature-class, append, error-000735

I have 5 fairly large Feature Classes with identical fields but different attribute data which I have been trying to merge/append together unsuccessfully.

When using merge_management the process runs successfully, but I am left with a feature class with many new fields created for each of the 5 feature classes (e.g. name1, name12, name123, name1234).

I really need to just retain the name field and add to it rather than creating new fields for the imported Series').

When I attempt to append rather than merge the operation fails with an

> ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR
>   000735: Input Datasets: Value is required Failed to execute (Append).

Find my code below:

(For Merging attempt)

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:/some.gdb"

fc_list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()


fc_list = [x for x in fc_list if "Pymade" in x]

print("Feature classes to join: " + str(fc_list))
print("Joining borough FCs into final output")
arcpy.Merge_management(fc_list, "MapPlutoAllBoro_{0}".format(today))
```

(For Appending attempt)

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:/some.gdb"

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(r"D:/some.gdb", "MapPlutoAllBoro_{0}".format(today))

fc_list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

fc_list = [x for x in fc_list if "Pymade" in x]

print("Feature classes to join: " + str(fc_list))
print("Joining borough FCs into final output")
arcpy.Append_management(fc_list, "MapPlutoAllBoro_{0}".format(today))
```

Comment: When you run arcpy.CreateFeatureclass for Append, supply a FC name such as fc_list[0] as the 4th parameter, this will define the fields.

Comment: Please include the output of those print statements, and your full error message including its line number.

Comment: It sounds like you need to look at a field FieldMappings object https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000078000000 to merge your name fields into one field, this is supplied as the 3rd parameter in the arcpy.Merge_management tool.

Answer (score 1):

In case your feature classes have different field names or types I would recommend to use `NO_TEST` parameter in Append tool.

You may try

```
arcpy.Append_management(fc_list, "MapPlutoAllBoro_{0}".format(today), schema_type = 'NO_TEST')
```

However, it doesn't prevent cases when geometries of all the feature classes are not the same.